# Show ListView in Custom alertDialog in android

Tags: android, listview, dialog

I have one Custom Dialog that I Create in xml file that contain one ListView.
I Create Custom Dialog with following code:

```
    useless = new Dialog(this);
    useless.setTitle("Floor " + floornum.getText().toString());
    useless.setCancelable(false);
    useless.setContentView(R.layout.uselessdialog);
    useless_list = (ListView) useless.findViewById(R.id.uselessdialog_List);
```

i have one ArrayList and want to show that into useless_list. how can do that?

Comment: And what is problem ?

Comment: how can show Arraylist into listview into dialog?

Comment: [What had you tried so far ?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13505518/1405983)

Comment: Just make a global adapter object and inflate it in your dialog and set that adapter to your ListView

Answer (score 1):

```
CustomAdapter adp;

useless = new Dialog(this);
useless.setTitle("Floor " + floornum.getText().toString());
useless.setCancelable(false);
useless.setContentView(R.layout.uselessdialog);
useless_list = (ListView) useless.findViewById(R.id.uselessdialog_List);
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>():
list.add("1");
list.add("2");
list.add("3");
list.add("4");
list.add("5");

adp = new CustomAdapter(YourActivity.this,list);
useless_list.setAdapter(adp);
```