# Custom Listview within a Dialog

Tags: android

I need to know how to inflate custom List Adapter on a dialog box within the same activity and how to implememt OnItemClick Listner on the custom list added into Dialog.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display a list view in an Android Alert Dialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762905/how-can-i-display-a-list-view-in-an-android-alert-dialog)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504781/custom-listview-inside-a-dialog-in-android

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    Button button;
    String[] data = new String[]{"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};
    ListView listView;
```

`@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);


}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    String day=data[i];
    Toast.makeText(this,day,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view==button){
    View layout = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_main2, null, false);
    listView = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("hello");
    builder.setView(layout);
    builder.show();
        }
      }
    }`