# Custom listview on AlertDialog multichoice

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, listview-adapter

I would like to create AlertDialog same as on the picture:
[image]

My code:

adapter_book_desc.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="15dip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <CheckedTextView
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" 
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
final CharSequence[] items = arr_book_title.toArray(new CharSequence[arr_book_title.size()]);
                final ArrayList<Integer> seletedItems = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(_context);
                builder.setAdapter(new adapterBookDesc(), null);
                builder.setTitle(_context.getString(R.string.alert_selectbook_message));

                builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected, boolean isChecked) {
                        if (isChecked) {
                            seletedItems.add(indexSelected);
                        }else if(seletedItems.contains(indexSelected)){
                            seletedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(indexSelected));
                        }
                    }
                }).setPositiveButton(R.string.button_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        String rr = ""; 
                        for (Object s : seletedItems){
                            rr += s.toString() + ";";
                        }
                        if(!rr.equals("")){
                            new saveBookInAutor().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, rr, selGroupParam);
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(_context, R.string.toast_select_newbookautor, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton(R.string.button_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    }
                });

                builder.create().show();
```

and class in BaseAdapter

```
class adapterBookDesc extends BaseAdapter
{
    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return arr_book_title.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        return arr_book_title.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_book_desc, null);
        }

        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1)).setText(arr_book_title.get(position));
        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2)).setText(arr_book_param.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

But in that look as on the picture it isn't displayed. However if to note as the comment of the line builder.setMultiChoiceItems - that everything it is displayed, except a multiple choice.

How to correct a code so that was as on the image. Multiple choice and title and the message in one item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must have to display two `TextView` in listing then you have to use custom adapter and you already using that, so you no need to use `builder.setMultiChoiceItems`, just customize your layout put checkbox in your layout and manage..

If you don't need two TextView then remove custom adapter.

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5459375/624069)