# return more than one value in multiple choice in Android

Tags: android, listview, if-statement

I have `ListView` with multiple choice items, I want whenever user check more than one item, return all its checked values.

```
SparseBooleanArray checked = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
    int position = checked.keyAt(i);
    if (checked.valueAt(i))
        selectedItems.add(String.valueOf(ard.getItem(position)));
}

String[] outputStrArr = new String[selectedItems.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {
    outputStrArr[i] = selectedItems.get(i);
    Pushbots.sharedInstance().setAlias(outputStrArr[i]);                  
}
...
```

In this case, only last checked value is took ...

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458989/android-listview-multiple-choice

Comment: Try `listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);  `

Comment: It does not work for set alias method